# Initial value problem $x'=e^{-|x|}$, $x(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $x=x(t)$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}=e^{-|x|}$, $x(0)=0$. Now I want to find the solution of this initial value problem. I want to solve it for $t\geq0$ and $t\leq0$. If $t\geq0$:

$\int_0^xe^{-s}ds=\int_0^t1dv$. Thus $e^{-x}=t+1$ and $x=-\ln(1+t)$.

For t<0:

$\int_x^0e^sds=\int_t^01dv$. Thus $x=\ln(1-t)$. But I know that the answer must be $x(t)=\ln(1+t)$ if $t\geq0$ and $x(t)=-\ln(1-t)$ if $t<0$. Who does see my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\dot{x}(t) = e^{-|x(t)|}$, then if $x \ge 0$, we have $\dot{x}(t) = e^{-x(t)}$ and so $e^{x(t)} \dot{x}(t) = 1$. Then $\int_0^t e^{x(\tau)} \dot{x}(\tau) d \tau = e^{x(t)}-1 = t$, which gives $x(t) = \ln(1+t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how you are separating variables. From $\frac{dx}{dt}= e^{-|x|}$ you multiply both sides by $e^{|x|}$ and $dt$ yielding $dx e^{-|x|}e^{|x|} = dt e^{-|x|} e^{|x|}$ or $dx e^{|x|} = dt$. This explains your error in both parts.